# Adding a numeric value to text entry in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in which it has combination of numeric and few text entries. I have to replace text occurrences with a specific number(0.0234) in cost columns(Cost1, Cost2, Cost3). Also empty values would remain as empty.

This is my data frame

```
Item=c("Item1","Item2","Item3","Item4","Item5")
Cost1=c(12,56,44,"","not available")
Cost2=c("Missing","",98,100,77)
Cost3=c(34,44,78,"","Missed to Enter")

Data1=data.frame(Item,Cost1,Cost2,Cost3)
```

It will be great if someone can help to solve this

Comment: What have you tried so far?  At present your question reads as "here is my problem, please do the coding for me".

Comment: Also note that your `Cost<x>` columns are coerced to character, so you *cannot* simply replace character entries with a numeric value without doing further (admittedly trivial) transformation.

Comment: For in-place of values, you can use `ifelse` or `replace`, though as others have pointed out, in R a `data.frame` generally allows only one "class" per column: once there is one string, all values are converted to strings, so (for instance) your `Data1$Cost1[1]` is actually `"12"` (string, not number). This means that you cannot do "math"-like things on them. It seems, though, that all of your strings convey "missingness" or "not-applicable", in which case you can likely replace them all with R's `NA` variable with `Data1[2:4] <- lapply(Data1[2:4], as.numeric)`, which will produce `NA`s.

Comment: In this specific case `apply(Data1[, grepl("Cost", colnames(Data1))], 2, \(x) ifelse(!grepl("[0-9]", x) & !(x %in% c("", "not available")), .0234, x))
` might work, but it's quite sensitive.

Comment: ``` Data1[2:4] <- lapply(Data1[2:4], as.numeric)``` By doing this empty also getting converted to NA. I want empty to remain as empty only.

Comment: See my suggestion and/or update your Q accordingly. You probably want to wrap into `Data1 <- as.data.frame(apply(...))`

Answer (score 0):

> Also note that your Cost columns are coerced to character, so you cannot simply replace character entries with a numeric value without doing further (admittedly trivial) transformation.

With that in mind (`numeric` as `character`), try this:

```
library(tidyverse) 

new_number <- "0.0234"

df <- mutate(
  df, 
  across(
    starts_with("Cost"),
    \(x) if_else(
      str_detect(str_squish(x), "^\\d+$") == FALSE & str_squish(x) != "",
      new_number, x)))

# --------------------------
   Item  Cost1  Cost2  Cost3
1 Item1     12 0.0234     34
2 Item2     56            44
3 Item3     44     98     78
4 Item4           100       
5 Item5 0.0234     77 0.0234
```

Answer (score 0):

The handling of "not available" appears unclear to me. If "not available" should be replaced as well, just drop it from the `ifelse()`-statement, i.e., use ifelse(test = !grepl("[0-9]", x) & x != "") instead.

Assuming your sample data accurately covers your data at hand, I suggest

```
Data1 <- as.data.frame(
  apply(X = Data1[, grepl("Cost", colnames(Data1))], 
        MARGIN = 2, 
        FUN = \(x) ifelse(test = !grepl("[0-9]", x) & !(x %in% c("", "not available")), 
                          yes = .0234, 
                          no = x)
        )
  )
```

gives

```
> Data1
          Cost1  Cost2  Cost3
1            12 0.0234     34
2            56            44
3            44     98     78
4                  100       
5 not available     77 0.0234
```

This approach does not rely on any external packages.